# fullpage.js background image not covering

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js with background images but the issue is they are not resizing automatically on page load. They only resize to cover the background when you scale the browser, onload they look very large, cropped and pinned to the upper top. Has anyone had this issue? I am using Chrome.

```
<div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section " id="section0">

            <div id="mainTourNav" class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li id="tourNav1"><a href="#"></a> </li>
                    <li id="tourNav2" class="tourNav"><a  href="#"> Slide 1</a></li>
                    <li id="tourNav3" class="tourNav"><a  href="#"> Slide 2 </a></li>
                    <li id="tourNav4" class="tourNav"><a  href="#"> Slide 3 </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="section1">
            <h1>It’s about Friends and Family. . .</h1>

        <div class="section" id="section2">
            <h1>It's about design. . .</h1>


        </div>
        <div class="section" id="section3">
            <h1>It’s about the game you love. . .</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS

```
/* Backgrounds will cover all the section
    * --------------------------------------- */
    #section0,
    #section1,
    #section2,
    #section3{
        background-size: cover;
    }

    /* Defining each section background and styles
    * --------------------------------------- */
    #section0{
        background-image: url(../img/Res-BG.jpg);
        padding: 15% 0 0 0;
    }
    #section1{
        background-image: url(../img/bg4.jpg);
        padding: 10% 4% 0 4%;
    }
    #section2{
        background-image: url(../img/bg3.jpg);
        padding: 10% 4% 0 4%;
    }
    #section3{
        background-image: url(../img/bg2.jpg);
        padding: 10% 4% 0 4%;
    }
    #section0 h1{
        color: black;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-style: italic;
        opacity: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your issue is about CSS, not about fullPage.js. You should make it clear how you want the image to "resize" or to "fit" the screen. Right now you are not telling us anything about it.

Comment: @Alvaro the Fullpage.js used this css to do the same effect. The `section { background:cover;}` I thought would do this but figured it out and answered below.

Comment: `section { background:cover;}` is not any code inside fullPage.js, it is just the code used for the example. As I said, its all about CSS, not about fullPage.js

Comment: Ya I guess I should have said the issue was a CSS thing from the example given by fullpage.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved. Basically I chaged:

```
#section0,
    #section1,
    #section2,
    #section3{
        background:cover;
    }
```

to

```
#section0,
    #section1,
    #section2,
    #section3{
        width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background-size:100% auto;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#section{
    background-image: url('http://www.fhdwallpapers.com/upload/2013/04/13/20130413064705-280c35c7.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That makes all the other section background photos not show up unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Add Follwing attributes to section3

```
#section3{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```